# Commenting on closed questions

Tags: support, comments, closed-questions

Why is it possible to comment on a closed question?

Comment: here is an example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548841/watin-to-click-the-yes-button-of-the-security-alert-in-ie6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Allows for people to post a case for re-opening the question. Especially if they don't have enough rep in order to cast a re-open.

It can also allow for a little tidy up of any loose threads that were fraying just before the closing of a question.

And it will allow a mod or one of the closers to explain why the question was closed in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

One reason I could think of: to let people without vote for reopen powers to let others know that they feel the question is valid.

I do not think that this is the reason it was done that way - only Jeff might have some insight on that - but for sure a good usage for it.

As Random beat me by 2 seconds, here another reason: to let the OP know what edits would help to turn it into a valuable question.

Comment: Beat you by only 2 seconds!

Comment: Total upvote on the comments helping out the Asker improve their question for re-openabilityessness.

Comment: What's this? Night of the rising dead? random shot you down! So stay on the ground.

Comment: Goaded him to consider bringing it back up because it was a good answer. Just lost out by 2 seconds.

Comment: @random: You are too good for this world ;)